# What is correct way to copy struct instance with fields in Go?

Tags: go, pointers, reference, copy

Today I discovered that I don't know how to copy instance in Golang.

While I have `deepcopy()` in Python, or `.clone()` in Rust.
And when i googled I saw that in go correct way is dereference. So i did that way.

But noticed that despite i define struct field as value, copy still points to same object in memory. And there was some mentions about specific conditions on array and slices, but not on maps(which is implicit type of http.Header). Those cases, apparently always passed by reference?

So my question is as in title: What is correct way to the deep copy of struct instance in go?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type (
    Client struct {
        headers http.Header
    }
)

func NewClient() *Client {
    return &Client{headers: make(http.Header)}
}

func (c *Client) Copy() *Client {
    newClient := *c
    newClient.headers.Add("Header", "ValueOne")
    return &newClient
}
func main() {
    origin := NewClient()
    copyOne := origin.Copy()
    fmt.Printf("originAddr: %p\t copyOneAddr: %p\n", origin, copyOne)
    fmt.Printf("originHeaders: %p\t copyOneHeaders: %p\n", origin.headers, copyOne.headers)
    fmt.Printf("originHeaders: %v\t copyOneHeaders: %v\n", origin.headers, copyOne.headers)
}
```

```
originAddr: 0xc000014040         copyOneAddr: 0xc000014048
originHeaders: 0xc000028c00      copyOneHeaders: 0xc000028c00
originHeaders: map[Header:[ValueOne]]    copyOneHeaders: map[Header:[ValueOne]]
```

Comment: It depends on what you’re copying. `http.Header` has a `Clone` method https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Header.Clone

Comment: Question about general case. I am curious about correct way. I may have struct with a lot of fields of custom types and nested struct. So question is about general approach.

Comment: There is no general approach because it depends on what you’re copying. If you have interfaces, pointers, maps or slices, you may need to recurse through those. The only general rule is that all assignments in Go are a copy of the value being assigned.